# What permissions are required to make a directory writable by php?

Tags: php, directory, chmod, writable

What permissions do I need to set up on a directory in order to make it writable by php?

By "writable", I mean copying and creation of new files within that directory automatically by php itself.

I'm testing this on a free host, and the default permissions are 755.

When I try executing a php script, that attempts to create another subfolder of that directory, and copy certain files in it, and it fails.

If I set it up to 777, it works fine, but I assume that doesn't work on all Apache versions because of security reasons?

Also, when creating new files, does php act as the "owner"?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever process that runs the PHP interpreter should should have a user account associated with it. Only that user needs write permission in the directory. So to answer your last question, it's usually `www-data` or `apache` that is the owner of that file.

Permission of `777` will work because it allows everyone to `read`, `write` and `execute` that directory but depending on your application this might be a security hole.